# Young woman finds herself in magical world then begins to remember living or visiting there as a child

Tags: story-identification, novel

Might have something to do with a bridge. I kind of remember a bridge on the cover.   Read this in the 80s. I think she was a princess sent away for safety reasons perhaps.

Comment: This is incredibly sparse and matches any one of potentially hundreds of works (Alice in Wonderland, for example). You need to be more specific.

Comment: This post [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/20774) will give you some checklists to work through to see if you can add more. In its current form, I suspect you'll find this question just gets closed.

Comment: That's a good start. So you think that she was a princess sent into the "real world" and then finds herself back in the fantasy world remembering who she is?

Comment: Yes. The details are vague. It's been a long time but I  think she even meets people that seem familiar.

Comment: @TeresaKeller: Your question got closed for being too broad, basically a lack of sufficient information, but you can still edit it with more details and get it re-opened. Do you remember any of the other characters? When you say "young woman", are you talking about a teenager? 20s? 30s? Do you remember anything about villains of the piece?

Answer (score 2):

The timing isn't right, and it involves being aware of where she came from, but *[Princess Nevermore](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3201014-princess-nevermore)* by Dian Curtis Regan involves a princess who gets transported from a fantasy world to Earth and has a bridge on the cover.

[image: Princess Nevermore book cover]

> Princess Quinnella is quite familiar with Mandrian truths. At 15, she's still allowed to come and go as she wishes in the kingdom of Mandria, visiting Melikar the wizard and playing at magic. But she knows that as soon as she turns 16, she will become a woman. A parade of suitors will court her until she chooses one--or the king chooses one for her--then comes marriage, childbearing, and royal protocol. But Quinn isn't ready for this life of predictability. More than anything, she wants to travel to "outer earth," the world above the wishing pool. When a magical mishap sends her to Earth, Quinn gets far more than she bargained for. As she is drawn deeper into this strange new world of skateboards, Halloween dances, and pizza, danger and adolescent intrigue surround her. There's only one problem: she doesn't know how to return to Mandria, and she's not even sure she wants to!

Comment: I don't think that's it.

Comment: That's the best possible answer on such a short question I have ever seen. This is on the level of someone asking "Do you know what this song is, goes like this: Nana nana lala nanaaaaa!" and you answering "Sponge Bob opening theme" and it being correct. Good job.